# Open Non editable url in a browser from activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I can open a url from my app but i want to make that url non editable or to hide the url from the user. So that the user can't edit it(address bar - read only) or if that is not possible then hide the address bar from the user.

Comment: Maybe you can use a webview instead of calling a browser?

Comment: It's impossible. It's not in your hands and depends on the browser's implementation only. A `WebView` is the only chance you got.

Comment: Thanks. I think i'll have to use the webview for my case since it seems that its not possible to render a browser's behavior from my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used webview to display the webPage